# Changing Security Permission using IIS

Tags: permissions, iis

One of our application hosted on register.com (Windows Server) hosting. In that application, we need to change security permission of a folder. The support of register.com suggested to change the security permission using IIS Manager. So we remotely connect the site using *connect to a site* option from IIS installed on my system. But I cannot find *Edit Permission* option, but local sites on the same IIS have that option.

[image: Screen Shot of IIS]

Please help me on this, am I missing anything on the IIS or there is any other method I can use to change the permission. File Manager of register.com not showing any options to change permission.

Note: I can access the folders and files from my system's Windows explorer using 'ftp' link and I can open ftp properties but there is no security tab, moreover it is showing  `the server does not support changing file permission`.

[image: Folder Properties]

Comment: What happens if you right click the parent website and click "Explore".... it'll open Windows Explorer where you should be able to right click the folder and change the permissions (if you've got the permissions to be able to manage permissions)...

Comment: @Kinnectus, thank you for your quick response. "Explore" option also not available, please see attached screen shot. I can access the folders and files from my system's Windows explorer using 'ftp' link and I can open ftp properties but there is no security tab, moreover it is showing it  ‘the server does not support changing file permission’. I am attaching screen shot of the same with my question